# How can I make a form with method="get" submit with Turbolinks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I have a search form on my page, and it is safe for Turbolinks to be enabled as it is using method="get"

Is there any easy way to have the form submit under control of Turbolinks (ie avoid page refresh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the turbolinks project, there's [issue #64](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/issues/64) where someone has written a Coffeescript implementation for Rails.

Add the code provided at that link.
It adds a `turboforms` function that needs to be called at page ready, like this:

```
$(turboforms);
```

I'm in the process of implementing this, I'll update my answer if I find out anything else that's useful.

Comment: Cheers, seems a dead end :(

Answer (score 25):

You could use something like this in your `application.js`:

```
// send get forms through turbolinks
$(document).on("submit", "form[data-turboform]", function(e) {
    Turbolinks.visit(this.action+(this.action.indexOf('?') == -1 ? '?' : '&')+$(this).serialize());
    return false;
});
```

Then, to enable any form to be sent with turbolinks you would need to add the `data-turboform` attribute to the form, like this:

```
<form action="..." method="get" data-turboform>
    ...
</form>
```

Comment: Using this with "form[method=get]" makes it even simpler :)